# IGrouping does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#, linq

I've been looking at other threads here to learn how to do a GroupBy in linq.  I am following the EXACT syntax that has worked for others, but, it's not working.

Here's the query:

```
var results = from p in pending
              group p by p.ContactID into g
              let amount = g.Sum(s => s.Amount)
              select new PaymentItemModel
              {
                  ContactID = g.ContactID, // <--- Error here
                  Amount = amount
              };
```

`pending` is a `List<T>` that contains, among other columns, `ContactID` and `Amount`, but those are the only two I care about for this query.

The trouble is, inside the the `select new`, the `g.` won't give me any of the columns inside the original list, `pending`. And when I try, I get:

> IGrouping `<int, LeadPurchases>` does not contain a definition for ContactID, and no extension method blah blah blah...

This is the SQL I am trying to emulate:

```
SELECT 
    lp.PurchasedFromContactID, 
    SUM (lp.Amount) 
FROM 
    LeadPurchases lp
GROUP BY 
    lp.PurchasedFromContactID
```

Comment: You'll want `g.Key.ContactID`

Comment: That gets me: int does not contain a definition for ContactID

Comment: Sorry - I'm not thinking straight. It should be simply `ContactID = g.Key` since you're only grouping by a single value

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are grouping on the basis of `ContactID`, so it should be the Key for the result, So you have to use `g.Key` instead of `g.ContactID`; Which means the query should be like the following:

```
from p in pending
group p by p.ContactID into g
let amount = g.Sum(s => s.Amount)
select new PaymentItemModel
       {
           ContactID = g.Key,
           Amount = amount
       };
```

**updates :**

If you want to perform grouping based on more than one column then the GroupBy clause will be like this:

```
group p by new
{
    p.ContactID,
    p.Field2,
    p.Field3
}into g
select new PaymentItemModel()
{
    ContactID = g.Key.ContactID,
    anotherField = g.Key.Field2,
    nextField = g.Key.Field3       
};
```

Comment: ok, this is looking promising!  I'll run some tests and report back.  Thank you!

Comment: @CaseyCrookston: Cool Happy coding

Comment: Ok, sweet that worked!  It will let me mark this as the answer in 3 minutes.  In the mean time, I know this is an addition to my OP, but... what if I wanted to group by more columns?  Would you mind adding to your answer to show what it would look like to group by one more column in addition to ContactID?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston : Yep I can help you, see the updates in my answer

Comment: how to return this example as list