# IGrouping<anonymous type:, string> does not contain a definition for '' and no extension method ''

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

**Goal**: Group by 2 columns

**Error**: This causes the error IGrouping does not contain a definition for 'Sub_ID' and no extension method 'SubID' accepting a first argument of type IGrouping

**Code**:

```
return db.View.Where(m => m.Mem_ID == Some_MemID && m.Last_Name.ToLower() == Search_MemLastName.ToLower()).GroupBy(t => new { t.Sub_ID, t.Mem_Seq }).OrderBy(t => t.Subs_ID);
```

I've also tried adding .key but that did not help.
Did not find a solution in [How to order IGrouping without changing its type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31287126/how-to-order-igrouping-without-changing-its-type) or [IGrouping does not contain a definition for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733775/igrouping-does-not-contain-a-definition-for)

Been looking at this for hours

Answer (score 2):

You are sorting the groups, and you have to access the grouped property(ies) through the `Key`:

```
.OrderBy(t => t.Key.Subs_ID)
```

Edit: If you only want to display distinct elements by `Sub_ID`, add .Select(x => x.First()) to select only the top result per group:

```
return db.View
    .Where(m => m.Mem_ID == Some_MemID && m.Last_Name.ToLower() == Search_MemLastName.ToLower())
    .GroupBy(t => new { t.Sub_ID, t.Mem_Seq })
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key.Subs_ID)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

With `GroupBy` you transformed an `IQueryable<T>` into an `IGrouping<TKey, T>`. The last `Select` is to *reduce* the groupings back to single elements.

Comment: I had tried that as well. It gives the error: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<<>> to System.Linq.IQueryable<>

Comment: The full error is : Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<System.Linq.IGrouping<<anonymous type: string Sub_ID, string Member_Seq>, Program.Data.View>> to System.Linq.IQueryable<Program.Data.View> . An explicit conversion exists

Comment: Either (a.) change your method return type to match that if you need to keep the grouped collections

Comment: Or, (b.) add `.Select(x => x.First())` to select only the top result per group, if that is what you need.

Comment: I only want it to display one row on the page if the Sub_ID is the same in the rows from SQL. Otherwise, it should display multiple rows on the page.

Comment: In other words, you only want to display distinct elements by `Sub_ID`. So pick option (b.) then.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if this is what you meant by the select, but this is what ended up working: .GroupBy(t => new { t.Sub_ID, t.Mem_Seq }).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Sub_ID).FirstOrDefault()).AsQueryable().OrderBy(m => m.Sub_ID);